# java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space collecting a lot of elements from an rdd in pyspark

Tags: java, out-of-memory, pyspark

I am trying to collect a large number of items from an rdd in pyspark.I get this error java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space. I think increasing the Java heap space will help.

[image]

I tried the following command java -Xmx2g to increase the java heap space and it did not work.

[image]

Anyone have any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: you should do that for the process you are trying to run. I dont know what rdd but it shoud be something like java -Xmx2g -jar a.b.c.jar or java -Xmx2g -classpath .. a.b.c.MainClass

Comment: Where can I find this jar or classpath? All I know is the location of the .ipynb file I am running when I get this error. Is that the classpath and classname I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the amount of memory Spark driver and executor processes can use by setting `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory`.

For example, you can run Spark like this:

```
/bin/spark-submit --name "My app" --master local[4] \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=2g \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=2g myApp.jar
```

You can configure these properties in a few different ways, see the [documentation on Spark configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).